# CREATE INDEX with condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL v5.1.

I would like to create index on a table by executing the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column_name)
```

But, I wan to firstly check if the index on that column has already been created or not, if not, create it (otherwise do not create). What is the SQL syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql doesn't have `IF NOT EXISTS` for `CREATE INDEX`. You can work it out by querying `information_schema.statistics` table. Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html), there is an example of stored procedure that does what you are looking for (search for "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS" on the page)

Comment: Well, yes I know MySQL does not have "IF NOT EXISTS" for "CREATE INDEX", I am seeking for a workaround, that's why I post my question here. But thank you for your suggestion, I will take a look.

Comment: @Mellon, you will probably find the post on `create_index_if_not_exists` stored procedure doing it for you. It'll seem like more work, but I think it'll do the trick; just not a one-liner :(

Answer (score 0):

You want [SHOW INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-index.html).

To get all the indexes on a table:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM table_name
```

MySQL allows you to add a `WHERE` clause to limit the results as well.

Lock the table while you're checking to see if the index exists (and if it doesn't exist, creating the index) so that another process doesn't create the index right after you've checked for it but before you've created it yourself.

Comment: No, you did not get my point of the question. I would like a SQL statement which do the thing like "CREATE INDEX idx_name on table_name (col_name) IF idx_name on col_name is not created" How can I both check and create it accordingly in pure SQL statement? Not only show the indexes. Well, show index is a good start, but it does not finish the thing I want.